# How to put IF statement in Excel based on my condition given?

Tags: c#, excel, if-statement

I am doing a savings account record for myself and I have this layout in Excel for now.

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va9rx.png)

I am quite good at C# and Java programming, but I'm not sure how to program an IF statement in an Excel cell. But here goes my algorithm anyway.

if TXN Type equals to Deposit, then
     valueAmount plus valueBalance. 
else if TXN Type equals to Withdraw, then
     valueBalance minus valueAmount

I would like to know how to translate this algorithm into Excel IF statement. The answer should appear in the balance cell and thus, not editable. The balance value will change prior to what I want to do (deposit or withdrawal) and the value stated in the amount cell.

Comment: So you want to use cell E2 in the calculations (valueBalance) and then store the results in cell E2?? If so, you can't. You will get a circular reference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming dollars & cents, put the initial balance in **E2** and in **E3** enter:

```
=IF(C3="Deposit",ROUND(E2+D3,2),ROUND(E2-D3,2))
```

Comment: Correct assuming there is no reason OP put "else if TXN Type equals to Withdraw" instead of simply "else".

Comment: If there are only two transaction types:  **Credit** and **Debit**, then the poster can save much typing by entering *Deposit* and leaving all the **Debits** blank...............because in most bank accounts, the debits far out-number the credits